# Convert a batch file function to bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch-file

I'm trying to convert this batch file that runs a python script into a bash script. I needed help converting a wait function in the batch file that waits for an action to complete into bash.

`script.py wait-for-job <actionID>` is the actual call that waits for the specific action to complete. The wait function basically assigns a value from the log file to a variable and then passes that variable as a parameter to a python script (script.py).

The log file is written continuously after each action and the last line (from which the action ID is fetched) looks something like this:
`02/10/2019 00:00:00 AM Greenwich Mean Time print_action_id():250 INFO Action ID: 123456`

The wait function in the batch file is as follows:

```
:wait
@echo off
for /f "tokens=11" %%i in (C:\Users\DemoUser\Dir\file.log) do ^
set ID=%%i
@echo on
script.py wait-for-job --action-id %ID%
EXIT /B 0
```

I tried implementing the same thing in bash like below but it did not seem to work (I'm new to shell scripting and I'm sure it's all wrong):

```
for $a in (tail -n1 /home/DemoUser/Dir/file.log); do
    ID=$($a | awk { print $12})
    script.py wait-for-job --action-id $ID
done
```

Comment: Few suggestions: (1) Add a `$` in front of the `(tail -n1 ...)` part. (2) `tail -n1` will return the last line in the .log file, is that what you want? (3) If you mean to pipe the contents of `a` into `awk`, you need to echo it first: `ID=$(echo $a | awk...)`. (4) If `script.py` is in your current directory, you need to prepend `./` to the file: `./script.py` (5) Linux requires a file to have the execution bit before it can be executed. It will be easier for you to call python instead: `python script.py...`.

Comment: Have a look at https://superuser.com/a/828740/358901 if you want to set the execution bit and call your script with `./script.py` instead of `python script.py`

Comment: check out https://batsh.org . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following reads each line of the file and pulls out the ID and uses it to call a py script. First we declare the paths and variables. Then we run a loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

typeset file=/home/DemoUser/Dir/file.log
typeset py_script=/path/to/script.py

readonly PY=/path/to/python

while IFS= read -r line ;do
        ${PY} ${py_script} wait-for-job --action-id $(${line} | awk { print $12})
done < "${file}"
```